# Как засечь таймер который по нажатию клавиши enter закончит работу? Питон

Tags: python, время, таймер

Пишу код где измеряю скорость печати на клавиатуре. Надо сделать так чтобы вовремя запуска input начался таймер а в момент того как пользователь нажмёт enter таймер остановится

Answer (score 1):

Перед тем, как запросить input() вы можете зафиксировать текущее время с помощью функции `time.time()`, после завершения input-а вы можете заново считать текущее время, и вычесть из него предыдущее значение.

> time.time() - время, выраженное в секундах с начала эпохи.

Если вам нужна высокая точность - например, в миллисекундах - придётся дописать ещё одну функцию:

```
import time

def current_milli_time():
    return round(time.time() * 1000)
```

Итоговый код будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
import time

def current_milli_time():
    return round(time.time() * 1000)

start_time = current_milli_time()
s = input("Введите ваше предложение: ")
end_time = current_milli_time()
print("Вы напечатали это предложение за", end_time - start_time, "миллисекунд.")
```

Comment: Спасибо! очень помогли